# Spring Security with JWT Roles not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

I am using Spring Boot and Java 14.

I am trying to get role based authentication working. I am using JWT. I can get authentication working, i.e. I get the JWT and use that token for all future requests successfully.

However, I cannot get the roles based authority working, i.e. I always get a 403 if the Security config tries to match an endpoint to a role.

For exmple, if I send the following request with a valid jwt where the user does have the correct role (`'approver admin'`):

```
GET http://localhost:8080/approvals

Header:  Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJyaWNoYXJkbWFyYWlzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTkyODgwNzUzLCJpYXQiOjE1OTI4NDQ3NTN9.MgiH5--a4U8phKz_jmjmBuxRt8iqhhcHHnxrhxGOQqM
```

I get the following reponse:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-06-22T16:56:22.113+00:00",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/approvals"
}
```

My code:

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("datasource1")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //auth.userDetailsService(approvalUserDetailsService);
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, (NOT disabled) as enabled FROM members "+
                "WHERE username = ?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT m.username, t.name as authority FROM members m " +
                "JOIN administrator a ON a.member_id = m.member_id " +
                "JOIN admin_type t ON t.admin_type_id = a.admin_type_id "+
                "WHERE m.username = ?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // set up the jwt auth
        http.cors().disable();
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()//.anyRequest().authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .and().exceptionHandling()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS); // don't manage sessions, using jwt
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        // define the role mappings
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("approver admin")
                .antMatchers("/approvals").hasRole("approver admin")
                .antMatchers("/hello").permitAll();
    }
```

**JwtRequestFilter.java**

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private ApprovalUserDetailsService approvalUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;

        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            username = jwtTokenUtil.extractUserName(jwt);
        }
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.approvalUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validteToken(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

**ApprovalUserDetailsService.java**

```
@Service
public class ApprovalUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        String sql = "SELECT username, password FROM members WHERE username = :userName";
//        String sql = "SELECT m.username, m.password, t.name as authority FROM members m " +
//                "JOIN administrator a ON a.member_id = m.member_id " +
//                "JOIN admin_type t ON t.admin_type_id = a.admin_type_id " +
//                "WHERE m.username = :userName";
        SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("userName", userName);
        User users = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, namedParameters, new UserDetailsRowMapper());
        return users;
        //        return new User("foo", "foo", new ArrayList<>());
    }

    class UserDetailsRowMapper implements RowMapper<User> {
        @Override
        public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            List<? extends GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<>();
            //String authority = rs.getString("authority");
            User user = new User(rs.getString("username"), rs.getString("password"), roles);
            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

In the `ApprovalUserDetailsService`, the `List<? extends GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<>();` is just an empty list.  Does this need to be populated with the 'approver admin' role?  Is that my problem?

The reason I have left it empty, because the tutorial I followed left it empty. I think the filter may only be used for getting the jwt, and not for the role validation, so it's not needed. Or am I incorrect and it needs to be populated?

If thought that the query in the `SecurityConfig.java` is were it gets the roles to validate. i.e.

```
    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT m.username, t.name as authority FROM members m " +
            "JOIN administrator a ON a.member_id = m.member_id " +
            "JOIN admin_type t ON t.admin_type_id = a.admin_type_id "+
            "WHERE m.username = ?");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> In the ApprovalUserDetailsService, the List<? extends
> GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<>(); is just an empty list.
> Does this need to be populated with the 'approver admin' role? Is that
> my problem?

Yes. It needs to be populated with the 'approver admin' . You can use `AuthorityUtils` to convert a string role name to the `GrantedAuthority` :

```java
    class UserDetailsRowMapper implements RowMapper<User> {
        @Override
        public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            String authority = rs.getString("authority");
            User user = new User(rs.getString("username"), rs.getString("password"), AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(authority););
            return user;
        }
    }
```

Also `hasRole("approver admin")` expects the user has the role `ROLE_approver admin` which the `ROLE_` prefix will be added automatically . Change to use `hasAuthority()` for the exact match without adding any `ROLE_` prefix :

```java
  http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin").hasAuthority("approver admin")
        .antMatchers("/approvals").hasAuthority("approver admin")
```

Comment: Hi Ken, thank you for your answer.  I tried your solution, i.e. changing it to `hasAuthority`, but I still get a `403`.

Comment: update my answer. yes . the user returned from the `UserDetailsService ` needs to populated with   'approver admin'

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try

Comment: The `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` object contains a `username`, `password` and a collection of `authorities`. Do you know how I can make the RowMapper return it as such? The commented out query returns a number of rows, so that won't work (`Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 19`).